# c# searching an arraylist

Tags: c#

In my code i have an arraylist called array.

I have filled it with numbers from 1 to 13

```
for(int i =1; i< 14; i++)
{
  array.items.Add(i)
}
```

Later in my code I also remove some of the elements at random. 
Example array.remove(3);

Now I wanna search, how many values of the elements
 in the arraylist is over specific number.

So, how many elements in the arraylist is over for example 5.

Anyone who knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why use an ArrayList?  This would be much easier with a `List<int>`.

Comment: I would like to use an arraylist in this project. Thanks for your tip though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this lambda expression:

```
int count = array.Cast<int>().Where(e=> e > 5).Count();
```

or even simpler:

```
int count = array.Cast<int>().Count(e=> e > 5);
```

You must be from Java right? I believe that you should use a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) in c#.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = array.Cast<int>().Count(x => x > 5);
```

OR change your arrayList to be an enumerable to allow.

```
int count = array.Count(x => x > 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.Cast<int>().Where(item => item > 5).Count();
```