# c# search arraylist problem

Tags: c#

In my code I have an arraylist, called heart, which contains numbers from 1-13.

```
heart.Add("any");

for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    heart.Add(i);
}
```

As you can see it also contains "any" placed in the first element. When I use this code to get the all of the elements that has a value over 5 I get an error.

```
int store = heart.Cast<int>().Where(item => item > 5).Count().ToString();
```

I get the error "Specified cast is not valid" and that's because of the
"any" I have in the first element. Could anyone help me fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# searching an arraylist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329849/c-searching-an-arraylist)

Comment: Don't post a follow-up as a new question. You can Edit your first one.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you just need the [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) method instead:

```
string store = heart.OfType<int>().Where(item => item > 5).Count().ToString();
```

`OfType` only returns values which are of the approriate type, ignoring others. See my [Edulinq blog post on it](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype.aspx) for more information.

As Sven shows, you can also use the overload of `Count` which takes a predicate, to remove the `Where` call:

```
string store = heart.OfType<int>().Count(item => item > 5).ToString();
```

(I've changed the variable type given that you're calling `ToString` at the end... again, you may want to think about this decision. It depends on how you're using it of course.)

However, I'd *strongly* advise you to use a strongly-typed collection instead of `ArrayList`. Think about what the collection is meant to hold - it seems odd to hold both strings and integers. What are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
int count = heart.OfType<int>().Count(item => item > 5);
```

`OfType` will filter the list and return only those elements that are the correct type, rather than `Cast` which tries to cast all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast the word "any" to an integer, that's pretty straight forward.

We'd have to know exactly what your trying to do with here, and how the array is used to really give a good recommendation.

Comment: Ye, I understand. Thanks for your answer, I got it working! :)

Comment: This should have been a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
Int store = heart.GetRange(1, heart.Count - 1).Cast<int>().Where(item => item > 5).Count().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `int` and you wanted values of 1-13, may I suggest you use an int value of 0 to represent 'any'?